# App Management Service Missing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, access

I barely have any idea what I'm doing with SharePoint as I come from a Linux admin background so forgive me if I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

I'm working with an existing SharePoint 2013 setup and I'm trying to enable Access Services following this [guide](http://www.sp2013blog.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37). I am stuck at the part where you add your new user to the `App Management Service` App with full control because It simply isn't in the `Manage Service Applications` page. When I go to `Manage services on server` I see `App Management Service` and it is started.

I'm guessing maybe you have to view the Central Admin page from a Managed Account but I don't have the login credentials for the one account set up like that.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While you should be able to see it, you can use [New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219690.aspx) to create it instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not seeing the `app management services` at `Manage Service Application page` then that's mean this services has not been provision. You have to create the App Management Services Application for this.

Please follow [this documents to configure i](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12516.sharepoint-2013-app-management-service.aspx)t.